# I have query to get some data but I need different result

Tags: sql, oracle

I use this in Oracle:

```
select to_char(a.insertdatetime) as insertdatetime , b.category, count(1) as count
  from daily a
     , server b 
 where status != 'OK'
 group by b.category
         , to_char(a.insertdatetime) 
 order by to_char(a.insertdatetime)
          , b.category;
```

This is the result:

[image: This is the result]

But I want the category to become a column and the count become data for each category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` as following:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    select to_char(a.insertdatetime) as insertdatetime , b.category
    from daily a, server b where status != 'OK'
    )
PIVOT
    (
    COUNT(1) FOR category IN (1 AS "1", 2 AS "2", 3 AS "3", 4 AS "4", 5 AS "5")
    )
ORDER BY insertdatetime;
```

### Update

Your original query should have `'` around the values in the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT` clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TO_CHAR(A.INSERTDATETIME) AS INSERTDATETIME,
            B.CATEGORY
        FROM
            DAILY A,
            SERVER B
        WHERE
            STATUS != 'OK'
    ) PIVOT (
        COUNT ( 1 )
        FOR CATEGORY
        IN ( 'ELASTIC' AS "ELASTIC", 'IS' AS "IS", 'IS_BPM' AS "IS_BPM", 'TC' AS "TC", 'UM' AS "UM" )
    )
ORDER BY
    INSERTDATETIME;
```

Comment: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Share the exact query that you are executing!!

Comment: that is the real for category

Comment: thanks sir its work but one more problem, the insertdatetime is not sorted correctly

Comment: 01-02-2020
01-03-2020
02-02-2020
02-03-2020
03-02-2020
03-03-2020
04-02-2020
04-03-2020
05-02-2020
05-03-2020
06-02-2020
06-03-2020
07-02-2020
07-03-2020
08-02-2020
08-03-2020
09-02-2020
09-03-2020
10-02-2020
10-03-2020

Comment: its order like that

Comment: because your date is not a date. it is a string as you have converted it to a string using `to_char`

Comment: thank you very much sir its done, you save my life :D

Comment: Sir then how me can get the last 10 data but still order by datetime

Comment: yes i remove the to_char but the case now i need to fetch 10 last data but still order by the date time

Comment: I add this to the query
ORDER BY
    INSERTDATETIME DESC
    FETCH FIRST 11  ROWS ONLY

but i need the data start from little one

Comment: What do you mean by little one?

Comment: 20-03-2020
19-03-2020
18-03-2020
17-03-2020
16-03-2020
15-03-2020
14-03-2020
13-03-2020
12-03-2020
11-03-2020
10-03-2020
the data is like this, but i want the 1st data is 10-03-2020

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to group only by `b.category`

```
select max(a.insertdatetime) as insert_date_time,
       b.category,
       count(*) as "count"
  from daily a
  join server b on b.id = a.server_id
 where status != 'OK'
 group by b.category
 order by insert_date_time, b.category;
```

where

- `count` is a reserved keyword that should be wrapped in quotes.
- there may exist only one column non-aggregated `b.category` in this
  case
- need at least one join condition among two tables such as `b.id = a.server_id`
- a column alias can directly be used within the `order by` list

Comment: My table doesnt have id.